# LinkedIn OAuth 2 Authorization URL says Bummer, something went wrong. We're having difficulty connecting.

Tags: linkedin-api

I am greeted with a page and I haven't been able to figure out what exactly it is that I am doing wrong .

I have done everything as suggested by the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context and ensured that the redirect URL I provided has been authorized from my app's page however I still see this page when I try to authorize . This is what the authorization URL looks like ( I removed client ID for reasons ) . My redirect URL is set to my localhost .

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fsocial-post%2Fcallback&state=MY_STATE&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_share

[image: linkedin response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this ! All I did was ensure that everything matched perfectly . The scopes in the URL and app page had to be the exact same and also I changed the redirect_uri from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and it works perfectly .